# Azure Logic App and Gmail create and authorize OAuth connection failed

Tags: azure, gmail, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Logic Apps and trying to create [Gmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/gmail/) connector and have followed the steps as mentioned in the documentation and run into the following error.

***Error:***

```
create and authorize OAuth connection failed
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Issue reproduced from my end and getting expected results by changing URI to https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect/gmail and by enabling Gmail API in Google API Console.**

- As you said followed the same [Gmail connector document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/gmail/) and created new project as gmailproject2 and the type as web application in Google API Console as shown in below image.
  [image]
- Getting the same error   **Create and authorize OAuth connection failed** while trying to sign in by entering correct client id and client secret .
  [image]
- Before getting this error i am getting this pop page as shown in below image. When i click on error message it shows the redirect uri should be like this **https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect/gmail**.Then i am getting the same error in Gmail connector Create and authorize OAuth connection failed.
  [image]
- By following that Gmail document initially i have taken redirect URI as mentioned in document .https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect .Then as shown in image added this https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect/gmail URI and click on save. Then tested by giving the client id and secret.
  [image]
- After adding that URI i am able to connect to my Gmail as you can see in image.
  [image]
  **Note**: After adding URI once check **Gmail API is enabled** as shown in below image. For that go to Enabled Apis and services in left navigation >> click on +Enable api and services>> then scroll down and click on Gmail API. check it is enabled or disabled. It should be in enable state so click on enable.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I Authorized redirect URIs, but still am getting the error 
Create and authorize OAuth connection failed.

Access blocked: azure-apim.net has not completed the Google verification process

azure-apim.net has not completed the Google verification process. The app is currently being tested, and can only be accessed by developer-approved testers. If you think you should have access, contact the developer.
If you are a developer of azure-apim.net, see error details.
Error 403: access_denied